# Modify a part of numpy array based upon a condition

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array with zeros and non-zeros and shape (10,10).
To a subpart of this array I need to add a certain value, where initial value is not zero.

```
a[2:7,2:7] += 0.5 #But with a condition that a[a!=0]
```

Currently, I do it in a rather cumbersome way, by first making a copy of the array and modifying the second array consistently and then copying back to the first.

```
b = a.copy()
b[b!=0] = 1
b[2:7,2:7] *= 0.5
b[b ==1] =0
a += b
```

Is there more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: `b = a[2:7,2:7]` and then `b[b!=0] += 0.5`. Test it with `print(a)`.

Comment: Great it works!! Thanks!

Comment: I forgot that unless you make a copy, b would still refer to a. 
Too much mutability, but sometime you can use for your good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Thomas Kühn, correctly wrote in the comment, its good enough to create a reference to that subpart of the array and modify it. So the following does the job.

```
b = a[2:7,2:7]
b[b!=0] += 0.5
```